# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I run it and choose a value in the combo-box, I receive this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type
>   'System.Data.DataRowView'.

This is my code:

```
private void cmbGroupname_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = new LinqtosqlDataContext();
    var group = db.TblQuestions;
    var q = db.SelectAllQuestionByGroupId(Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)cmbGroupname.SelectedItem)["GroupID"]));
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: That's because the SelectedItem of the combo-box is a string. Obviously, you can't convert it to `DataRowView`. Here's where you're getting the error: `(DataRowView)cmbGroupname.SelectedItem`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear, you are trying to cast `cmbGroupname.SelectedItem`, a string, to DataRowView. How about:

```
var q = db.SelectAllQuestionByGroupId(Convert.ToInt32(cmbGroupname.SelectedValue));
```

Comment: This code is wrong.in fact i want choose the "GroupID" in combobox.my combobox Include string values "GroupName".

Comment: With the following code I have received "GroupName" And "GroupID" in combobox and now i want just choose the "GroupID".

Comment: public void Frmquestion_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var db = new LinqtosqlDataContext();
            var group = db.TblGroups;
            foreach (var t in group)
            {
                cmbGroupname.Items.Add(t.GroupName);
                cmbGroupname.ValueMember = Convert.ToString(t.GroupID);
            }
        }